# My HTML H1 Header won't become bold with <b> or <strong>

Tags: html

I am trying to make a header bold, but it won't. I have tried using `<b>` and `<strong>`, I have tried inside of the `<h1>` element and outside, but none of it works. Here's the snippet:

```css
.title {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 98px;
  color: #00FF00;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Taemon-Coolz </h1>
<h1 class="title">Here.</h1>
```

(I didn't include the strong tags because there were so many variants.)

Comment: What does your CSS declaration look like for `.title`?

Comment: you include your css?

Comment: .title{
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 98px;
  color: #00FF00;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;

Comment: `h1`  already have `bold` property . You can see the difference if `<b>` applied on paragraph

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways.

1. CSS
2. You must put `<b>` inside of `<h1></h1>`
3. You must put `<strong>` inside of `<h1></h1>`

```css
.title{
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Hello World</h1>
<h1><b>Hello World</b></h1>
<h1><strong>Hello World</strong></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding
`h1{font-weight: bold;}`
Or in your case you can also use
`.title{font-weight: bold;}`
In css

Comment: I tried that. It did not work.